# asp.net mvc with entity framework database first domain model validations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation, database-first

I'm Developing ASP.NET MVC Web Application project, and I'm using Entity Framework Database First Approach, So I would like to make validations on generated model classes, I know if i make validations on them directly, then my model validations will be overwritten every time my domain models are regenerated.

So I made a research, and found two approaches to use for this scenario:

1- Using buddy classes ([How to add validation to my POCO(template) classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128303/how-to-add-validation-to-my-pocotemplate-classes/5128373#5128373)).

2- Using ViewModels and Auto-mapping them to my Entities ([Designing an MVC repository using ViewModels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943210/designing-an-mvc-repository-using-viewmodels)

I see some sort of redundant code in these two methods, so, my question is:

Which one of the two approaches is best to flow?

Answer (score 0):

1) This is the correct solution for adding validation metadata for the Entity Framework objects. The validation will be triggered automatically by EF before calling `SaveChanges()`

2) This is an aproach for creating `Data Transfer Objects` from your EF objects. You normally do this when you want to return the objects to the client (like in JSON format) - and you don't want to expose all the EF specific properties (like navigation properties, primary keys etc)